# Regex for month matching with format "M/DD/YY Time"

Tags: regex

i am trying to match date as below:
"3/21/22 6:00 AM" so this is "M/DD/YY Time"

regex which i am trying to write is:

```
^((0?[1-9]|1[012])|\d|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(22) ([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ([AaPp][Mm])$
```

and it is not catching the first "3" so month is not included. Why?
I do not understand this OR statement in Regex "|" in this case.
So 1\d 2\d i do not know how this is working

Can you please help
Best
Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, `((0?[1-9]|1[012])|\d|1\d|2\d|3[01])` matches numbers from `0` to `31`. Next comes the `\/22` pattern, so this part only allows to numbers in the date part only.

You need to amend the regex to

```js
^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/([12]?\d|3[01])\/(22) (0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d ([AaPp][Mm])$
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QuTlsK/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(0?[1-9]|1[012])` - Group 1: an optional `0` and then a non-zero digit or `10`/`11`/`12`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([12]?\d|3[01])` - Group 2: an optional `1` or `2` and then a digit, or `30`/`31`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(22)` - Group 3: `22`
- - space
- `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - Group 4: an optional `0` and then a non-zero digit or `10`/`11`/`12`
- `:` - a colon
- `[0-5]\d` - a digit from 0 to 5 and then any one digit.
- - space
- `([AaPp][Mm])` - Group 5: `am` or `pm`
- `$` - end of string.